# Do I have to create IAM role to run "aws ec2 describe-security-groups"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am owner of one EC2 instance. I can ssh to virtual server by key.pem. My question is to print security-group content (inbound and outbound in one page) of this EC2 instance, do I have to attach IAM role to this instance (so that I can use aws ec2 command) ?

I just wondering, if I am the owner of this instance, I shall be able to do anything without extra granting....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM permissions has nothing to do with EC2 instances and the owner of the instance is the AWS account. Just imagine what will happen if one of your IAM user can run any commands by just launching an instance. 
You can run "aws ec2" command from your local machine/laptop after installing AWS CLI. If you choose to do so, you have to configure the CLI with the access keys of an IAM user with proper permission. Same applies to EC2 instances, but you can leverage IAM role so that you don't have to use access keys and instead use temporary credentials provided by the IAM role (recommended).
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-quick-configuration